# e.tabIndex contains nothing..?

Tags: titanium

e.tabIndex contains nothing..?

I have application which has four tabs and

I would like to get the 'swipe' gesture and change the current active tab.

However I cant get the current activeTab.

Some sample code says you can get active tab number 'e.tabIndex' though...

my index.js

```
$.mainTabGroup.addEventListener('swipe',function(e){

    var tabIndex = e.tabIndex;
        var lastIndex = $.mainTabGroup.getTabs().length - 1;
    Ti.API.info(tabIndex);// somehow null????
    Ti.API.info(lastIndex);
        //switch the tab here.
});
```

my index.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup backgroundColor="white" id="mainTabGroup">
        <Tab id="byFav" title="fav" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
        <Window title='fav'>

            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="byLatest" title="latest" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
            <Window title='latest'>

            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="byCat" title="category" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
            <Window>

            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="byDate" title=" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
            <Window>

            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swipe event callback does not have any tabindex. You may get active tab using activeTab Property or getActiveTab method

```
$.mainTabGroup.addEventListener('swipe',function(e){
    var tabIndex = $.mainTabGroup.activeTab;       //using property
    var tabIndex = $.mainTabGroup.getActiveTab();  // using method
});
```

Comment: Thanks,$mainTabGroup.getActiveTab() returns the current activeTab. How can I get the next tab and switch???I think if I can get the number insted of object I can switch though...

Comment: you can save tabIndex in App level property ,say initially store 0 in it. on swiping left and right you can add or subtract 1 from that property value. then use setActiveTab method or activeTab property to update current tab while swiping